# In Windows networking and networking in general, is 1 Megabit/s = 1000 or 1024 Kilobits/s?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, internet, bandwidth

**Background:**

I was recently experimenting with using throttling inside some applications to prevent them from using the full bandwidth of my Internet connection, and I whilst testing the current throughput using the Speedtest Windows application on Windows 10, I came across a strange scenario whereby the throughput reported from the task manager network monitor was significantly higher than that shown in Speedtest: Approx. 403 Mbps in Task Manager vs 387.30 Mbps in Speedtest (see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9ahc.png)).

This is approximately a 4.1% difference, and it got me thinking about since Windows measures file sizes using Base 2 (e.g. Kibibytes (KiB)) and not Base 10 (e.g. Kilobytes (KB)), whether this also applies to its network monitor or to Speedtest, since if Speedtest used Mib/s and Windows used Mb/s, then the difference in readings should be (1024/1000)^2 or 4.9% which is close to
what was observed. However, since Speedtest [defines 1 Mbps as 1000 kbps](https://help.speedtest.net/hc/en-us/articles/360039162713-What-do-mbps-and-kbps-mean-), this seems an unlikely explanation, but I couldn't find any concrete information about which system Windows' networking uses.

In addition, this caused another question about whether the rest of the networking industry, such as:

- ISPs
- NIC, Router, Switch, etc. Manufacturers
- The rest of the networking industry

also adhere to Base 2 numbering system or to Base 10? My guess based on what I've seen and what I've been taught is that Base 10 is used in most network engineering (e.g. Gigabit Ethernet is also called 1000BASE which denotes 1000 Mbps), but I wasn't sure if this was the case for all of the categories above.

**Questions:**

1. Does Windows use Base 2 or Base 10 numbering in its network monitor?
2. Does the networking industry in general (such as in the example products above) use Base 2 or Base 10 numbering for throughput ratings?
3. If Windows does use Base 10 like Speedtest, what could be causing these different readings between the two applications?

Comment: I can't fully answer your question, because I don't know what Windows uses. Networking uses 8b/10b encoding to have an error detection, then it's Base 10.

Comment: Mega bit per second is usually base 10, Mega Byte per second is usually base 2. This applies as long as it's the case and doesn't if it's not. Historically networks use base 10 while PCs in most cases use base 2 and at the same time they can differ depending on context as the SI units for base 2 haven't been standardized for that long (in comparison).